# How to render a json in the same line? (LWC)

Tags: json, table, lighting-web-component

I have a Json like bellow. I want to render `complement` like in the picture.
P.S: I'm able to access the other columns normally.

**JSON**

```
    {
      "postalcode": "1234",
      "street": "ABC",
      "number": "1"
      "complement": [
        {
          "type": "B",
          "name": "XYZ",
          "description": "3"
        },
        {
          "type": "C",
          "name": "CDE",
          "description": "TR"
        },
        {
          "type": "D",
          "name": "AAA",
          "description": "5"
        }
      ],
    }
    {
      "postalcode": "2222",
      "street": "BBB",
      "number": "2"
      "complement": [
        {
          "type": "E",
          "name": "NDP",
          "description": "3"
        },
        {
          "type": "F",
          "name": "DDD",
          "description": "FR"
        }
        
      ],
    }
  }
```

**How can I reder the `complement` like it?**
[image]

**HTML**

```
  <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open slds-modal_large" aria-modal="true">
        <div class="slds-modal__container">
            <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-modal__close slds-button_icon-inverse">
                <svg class="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon_large" aria-hidden="true">
                    <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#close"></use>
                </svg>
                <span class="slds-assistive-text">Cancel and close</span>
            </button>
            <div class="slds-modal__header">
                <h1 class="slds-text-heading_medium">TITLE</h1>
                <h2 class="slds-text-title">SUB</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-modal__content" id="modal-content-id-1">
                <div class="slds-lookup" data-select="multi" data-scope="single" data-typeahead="true">
                    <div class="slds-form-element slds-p-top_medium slds-p-horizontal_medium slds-m-bottom_small">
                        <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_right">
                            <button
                                class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_right searchButtonStyle">
                                <lightning-button-icon icon-name="utility:search" variant="bare"
                                    alternative-text="Search" aria-hidden="true" onclick={handleSearch}>
                                </lightning-button-icon>
                            </button>
                            <input type="text" id="lookup" class="slds-input" role="combobox" aria-activedescendant=""
                                aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="lookup-grouped-table-id-1"
                                aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-expanded="true" placeholder="Search..." />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_cell-buffer slds-no-row-hover"
                        role="listbox" id="lookup-grouped-table-id-1">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <template for:each={columns} for:item="col">
                                    <th key={col}>
                                        {col}
                                    </th>
                                </template>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                            <template for:each={rows} for:item="row">
                              
                                    <tr key={row}>
                                        <td key={row} class="slds-text-align_left">
                                            <div key={row} class="slds-form-element__control">
                                                <input type="radio" id={row} value={row} name="default" checked="" />
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td key={row}>
                                            <div class="slds-truncate" title={row.postalcode}>{row.postalcode}</div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td key={row}>
                                            <div class="slds-truncate" title={row.street}>{row.street}</div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td key={row}>
                                            <div class="slds-truncate" title={row.number}>{row.number}</div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td key={row} for:each={row.complement} for:item="compl">
                                            <div class="slds-truncate" title={compl.name}>{compl.description}</div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </template>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-modal__footer slds-modal__footer_directional">
                <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" aria-label="Cancel and close">Cancel</button>
                <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral">New Account</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open" role="presentation"></div>
</template>
```

**WHAT I GOT:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON in your question is not valid. Assuming it would be an array of objects you could do something like this:

```
data = [
    {
        "postalcode": "1234",
        "street": "ABC",
        "number": "1",
        "complement": [
            {
                "type": "B",
                "name": "XYZ",
                "description": "3"
            },
            {
                "type": "C",
                "name": "CDE",
                "description": "TR"
            },
            {
                "type": "D",
                "name": "AAA",
                "description": "5"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "postalcode": "2222",
        "street": "BBB",
        "number": "2",
        "complement": [
            {
                "type": "E",
                "name": "NDP",
                "description": "3"
            },
            {
                "type": "F",
                "name": "DDD",
                "description": "FR"
            }
        ]
    }
];
// This adds a getter with name complements to each object in the data array
data.forEach((item) => {
    Object.defineProperty(item, 'complements', {
        get: function() { 
            // create a string containing the name and description for each element and concatenate those strings separated by a comma and space
            return this.complement.map((c) => `${c.name} ${c.description}`).join(', '); }
    })
});

console.log(data[0].complements); // should now print "XYZ 3, CDE TR, AAA 5"
console.log(data[1].complements); // should now print "NDP 3, DDD FR"
```

Comment: Is it for javascript LWC? 'm getting "e.forEach is not a function"

Comment: It is javascript. With that error your data is probably not an Array

Comment: I managed to adjust...Now I'm getting "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')"